# How can we use a different masterpage for annoymous and authenticated users?

Tags: master-page, anonymous-authentication

Is there a way to load a different master page if I can identify the user to be annonymous?

Comment: In my experience the "master page switching" approach leads to a great deal of confusion and complexity. I would try to avoid it if you can find another way of achieving what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do it at page level, you can assign a different master page on "OnPreInit" event. Below is the example to do it on layout page if you have publishing site :

```
public class MyPublishingLayoutPage:PublishingLayoutPage
    {
        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            if (Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous)
            {                
              SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
              this.MasterPageFile = "~/_catalogs/masterpage/anonymous.master";                   

            }
        }

    }
```

If you have many pages, I would recommend to use *HttpModule* to hook *PreInit* handler into the page. Below is the example :

```
public class AnonymousMasterModule: IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute+= new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
                if (!requestUrl.Contains(".aspx"))
                    return;               

                 Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
                 if (page != null)
                    page.PreInit += new EventHandler(page_PreInit);                

        }

        void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Page page = sender as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                if (Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAnonymous)
                {
                    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                    page.MasterPageFile = "~/_catalogs/masterpage/anonymous.master";
                }
            }

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to have a different look and feel for different users, you can use a single Master Page, and include steps that only target specific profiles (anonymous users in your case).

Search the internet for the following terms: SPSecurityTrimmedControl and AnonymousTemplate.

It is what I use on this draft page:

http://usermanagedsolutions.com

For authenticated users, the site is just an out of the box SharePoint 2010 page. I add a css layer for anonymous users to modify the page width and hide the top bar.

Answer (score 5):

[This post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43377/SharePoint-Dynamically-Change-Master-Page.aspx) describes how can you change masterpage dynamiccally.

Comment: This is sharepoint 2007, so I don't have access to code behind like that. Is there a way to do it 2007?

Comment: sorry, I don't know another solution.

Comment: If you working with SharePoint 2007, you can create HttpModule, and change the master page as described in the post. I don't see a reason related to SP2007 why you can't do that if you have SP on dedicated server. We used this approach to customize design of application pages in SP2007. Steps:

Comment: Steps: 1. create HttpModule that performs changing master page for anonymous users. 2. deploy it in GAC 3. register Module in web.config - Thats all.

Comment: @mdrussell0779 : You can create a code behind and implement what Alexander has suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You can use two options only for targeting content to users (not change of master page):

1. Audience for Server version - http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/sortinganditerating/article.php/c13255__2/ and for 2010 but the concept seems to be the same in 2010 - http://blog.mastykarz.nl/content-targeting-anonymous-users-sharepoint-server-2010-part2-2/
2. SPSecurityTrimmedControl - which allows showing content based on permissions -
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spsecuritytrimmedcontrol%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use an Http Module to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You can include within the Master Page steps that only target specific profiles (anonymous users in your case).

Search the internet for the following terms: SPSecurityTrimmedControl and AnonymousTemplate.

It is what I use on this draft page:

http://usermanagedsolutions.com

For authenticated users, the site is just an out of the box SharePoint 2010 page. I add a css layer for anonymous users to modify the page width and hide the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same what you asked, See the answer:  [How can we use a different masterpage for annoymous and authenticated users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21679/a-seperate-masterpage-for-annoymous-users/21690#21690)

You can do with httpmodule or a code-behind in a page

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example in my publishing site for web part pages. But its not work.

i debug the code but event handler is not call the below method.

void page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)

Please advice...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you register the HttpModule in web.config? Google up "HttpModule" and how to use it.