# Can I set master page based on whether user is anonymous or not?

Tags: master-page, custom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A seperate masterpage for annoymous users?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21679/a-seperate-masterpage-for-annoymous-users)

Stemming from a previous suggestion on how I can display my sharepoint site completely differently to anoymous users, I am wondering if I can somehow change the master page the user sees based on if they are logged in or not?

IE, User anon comes to the site, they get a basic page based on a master page with a single content placeholder that says "hello world", but if user then visits settings.aspx and logs in, the master page swaps over to default.master

Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed - it is a duplicate. Merging these two questions.